# Having trouble with string concatenation

Tags: java

I was trying to concatenate a string to itself + something else, like this:

```
String example = " "
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (condition OK) {
        example = example + "\nAnother text";
    }
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, example);
```

In my mind, it should've print " (new line)Another text" but it seems to work only with the last entry in my "Another text". Like, if the condition inside the "for" loop is OK 3 times, it prints " (new line)Another text(3)" instead of " (new line) Another Text(1) (new line) Another text(2)...

Any idea of what may be happening?

EDIT: after realizing that my code was fine, I followed afzalex recommendation and found out the error was in my condition. Thanks bro

Comment: The code you provide is alright. The problem must be in condition you are providing.

Comment: What's `if (condition OK) { ... }`?

Comment: I don't think the message dialog displays newlines; try replacing `\n` by some spaces?

Comment: It passed the condition and entered the block to execute the concatenation

Comment: I don't see any code for printing number inside brackets `(1)` which you are expecting. BTW, instead of doing String concatenation try using StringBuffer or StringBuilder based on which suits you better based on no. of threads and all.

Comment: What I wrote inside parentheses isn't suppose to be printed, I was just expliciting it meant to be different from the previous

Comment: afzalex I've tested several times with the same strings and condition, just changing the amount of time the condition went OK. It always deletes what is previously written and prints "example" as if it were a blank space

Comment: it prints "example" or value that variable example holds?

Comment: mastah the value, but a single time. The second time it enters the if block, its like it has a blank space in the variable, and prints only the second text

Comment: Don't put "RESOLVED" in the title. Accept one of the answers instead, If no answer is correct, you can write one yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below program I got expected output.

```
    String example = " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i == 1 || i == 3) {
            example = example + "\nAnother text";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(example);
```

Output:

```
Another text
Another text
```

So, probably it could be something wrong with `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, example);` If it is being interpreted as HTML in the end, then better use `</br>` instead of `\n`, that can give you new line.